# Can continuation in `IAuthorizationFilter.ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsync` be null?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a standard ASP.NET auth filter implementation like this.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsync(HttpActionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
{
       await OnAuthorizeAsync(context);
       return context.Response ?? await continuation();
}
```

Can `continuation` be `null` in `IAuthorizationFilter.ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)` and should I add null check?